# How to enable Partitioning in oracle 11g (windows 8)?

Tags: database, windows, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting the Error as:

```
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Partitioning while trying to create table with partition.
```

I have solution for linux and unix systems here:

```
$ cd $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib
$ make -f ins_rdbms.mk part_on
$ make -f ins_rdbms.mk ioracle
```

Can any one provide solution for windows ?

Note:

```
select * from v$option where parameter='Partitioning';

PARAMETER
----------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
Partitioning
FALSE
```

Thanks

Comment: What edition are you using?  You can find out from `select * from v$version;`

Comment: You have to buy this feature from Oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1983569), if you indeed have the Oracle *Enterprise* Edition AND the license option for partitioning, you need to enable it through the OUI (Oracle Universal Installer).

Shutdown the database, open the OUI from your Oracle Home, and install "Partitioning".